# What's Site App in django used for?

Tags: django

What's Site App in django used for?

I'm confusing about that, what's that used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it to serve several virtualhosts from same Django installation, and differ them by the host. This can be useful if you want ho have something like male.dating.example.com and female.dating.example.com, both basically with same applications, but with differed data and one with pink design and the other with blue design.

You will then use site application to access data you want to have different, for example binding users to certains sites, switching templates according to site etc.

Comment: That's a good example. At work we've made a bunch of websites for a leisure company, each gym/pool/golf course has a cookie cutter style website with the same forms, and pages but a slight variation in the template css. It would be great for something like that, or blogs on different subdomains.